# Property editor with categories

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, propertyeditor

I'm writing an app in Java and swing using Netbeans, and I need property editor (like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/uiswing/learn/nb-swing-8b.png)). How I can add it to my application?

Comment: Hmmm... A property editor. I searched for it a few months ago. I didn't found anything interesting. So I wrote some classes, together over 1500 lines of code....

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux is your code available?

Comment: @MatthewCornell: While it is still under heavy development, it's not available to the public. It contains over 25000 lines of code. It still is a generic project and completely application agnostic. The reason why it's not public yet, is because I'm still not sure what license I want to use and wether I want this to be commercial or not, because it is *super* powerfull and let's you create applications in no-time (really, I build a fully functional EER diagram designer in only 6 hours (screenshot here: http://puu.sh/oVbS0/3741907ec5.png )).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend using [the NetBeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/). It's really simple and well documented rich client platform. Then **you can use exactly the same property editor as in NetBeans.** Porting from plain Swing applications to NeatBeans RCP is quite simple too.

Comment: The first link - without categories, the second - it's about property editor in JFormDesigner...

Comment: Oops right - I missed category requirement. Look at updated response.

Comment: @zacheusz I would need to use the property widget inside my own code, but I had no luck finding how to do this. Do you have any pointers, please?

Comment: @MatthewCornell please find a property editor example here https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-property-editors.html

Comment: @zacheusz Thanks. It looks like those are instructions for using it within NetBeans, but not in external non-NB projects, no?